# Python multiprocessing pool.map explanation

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I still learning Python. To me, this code isn't completely obvious about showing exactly how 'pool mapping' works on https://docs.python.org:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numb_list = [1, 22, 333]
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, numb_list))
```

So... its plugging each index of the list[1, 22, 333] separately into separate processes of the same function all running on different cores?
If so, how can I determine details about a certain iteration?
Example if I edited the function because I wanted to know the length of a certain element in the list [1, 22, 333]

```
def f(x):
    if len(x) >= 3:
         print("Big input")
    return x*x
```

Does pool insert the whole list at once into each process running the function or parts of the list? Can I check the length of an element input this way?
Is there a way I can use a for loop instead of map to distinguish which iteration or element is being currently input?

Comment: You're correct, it passes each element separately into separate processes.

Comment: Okay. So I'm guessing I can check within the function for the length of x which should be a single element in the list for the current process? Not a lot of people are good at coding parallel programs?

Comment: Yes, that should be right.

Answer (score 0):

It nearly equals to:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

results = []
for item in numb_list:
    process = Process(target=f, args=(item,))
    process.start()
    # insert process result in to results
```

`map` will unpack this iterable parameter and send each item to each process.

Comment: Q. 1. Where does `map` come into picture here. 2. Is it possible to make batches of data and distribute it across different processes?

Comment: A. 1. The similar structure. `Pool` is more complicated than this, it maintains a process pool and a task queue. 2. Sure, but you need to adjust the data into something like `[[first batches], [second batches], [third batches]]`. Actually, in reality, we use other packages for help.